# Inline declared MySQL 'unknown column'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, row

Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
$resultadosPromediados = R::getAll("SELECT count(*) as total, 
                                    SUM(dialogue_score) / total as dialogue_score, 
                                    SUM(consulta_general_score) / total as consulta_general_score, 
                                    SUM(tarea_score) / total as tarea_score, 
                                    SUM(foro_calificacion_score) / total as foro_calificacion_score,  
                                    SUM(foro_respuesta_score) / total as foro_respuesta_score
                                    FROM ranking
                                    WHERE created = :ultima_feha",
                                    array(':ultima_feha' => $fecha));
print_r($resultadosPromediados);
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught [42S22] - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total' in 'field list' thrown in /home/ASDFASDF/public_html/ADSFADSF/rb.php on line 265

How can I use the total rows to divide the sum of them to get an average reading?

Comment: You cannot use the alias `total` in the same select list. You will either need to use `COUNT(*)` or wrap the whole thing in a derived table which first calculates the aggregates inside then does the division outside.

Comment: `avg(dialog_score)` might be more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a variable:

```
SELECT @total := count(*), 
    SUM(dialogue_score) / @total as dialogue_score, 
    SUM(consulta_general_score) / @total as consulta_general_score, 
    SUM(tarea_score) / @total as tarea_score, 
    SUM(foro_calificacion_score) / @total as foro_calificacion_score,  
    SUM(foro_respuesta_score) / @total as foro_respuesta_score
FROM ranking
WHERE created = :ultima_feha
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `ALIAS` that is generated on the same level of the `SELECT` statement. You have to choices

One, to use the whole expression,

```
SELECT  count(*) as total, 
        SUM(dialogue_score) / count(*) as dialogue_score, 
        SUM(consulta_general_score) / count(*) as consulta_general_score, 
        SUM(tarea_score) / count(*) as tarea_score, 
        SUM(foro_calificacion_score) / count(*) as foro_calificacion_score,  
        SUM(foro_respuesta_score) / count(*) as foro_respuesta_score
FROM    ranking
WHERE   created = :ultima_feha
```

Second, to use subquery,

```
SELECT  total,
        dialogue_total / total AS dialogue_score,
        consulta_general_total / total AS consulta_general_score,
        tarea_total / total AS tarea_score,
        foro_calificacion_total / total AS foro_calificacion_score,
        foro_respuesta_total  / total AS foro_respuesta_score
FROM
        (
            SELECT  count(*) as total, 
                    SUM(dialogue_score) as dialogue_total, 
                    SUM(consulta_general_score) as consulta_general_total, 
                    SUM(tarea_score) as tarea_total, 
                    SUM(foro_calificacion_score) as foro_calificacion_total,  
                    SUM(foro_respuesta_score) as foro_respuesta_total
            FROM    ranking
            WHERE   created = :ultima_feha
        ) alias
```